# Error in openxlsx::read.xlsx/download.file after updating R to 4.2.1

Tags: r, windows, openxlsx

After update my Rgui to 4.2.1 version I found an enconding issue which was apparently solved by [Problem with opening scripts in updated version of R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096770/problem-with-opening-scripts-in-updated-version-of-r). Briefly: my R files were opening empty and the solution was simply change default encoding to UTF-8.

But other issue came with (or just was there from the beginning). When I tried to read some xlsx directly from url, I got this error message:

```
In download.file(url = xlsxFile, destfile = tmpFile, cacheOK = FALSE,  :
URL 'https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/historicaldevelopment/maddison/data/mpd2020.xlsx': Timeout of 100000 seconds was reached
```

**When I went back to R 4.0.5, the problem disappeared!**

*Reproducible example*

```
url_maddison = "https://www.rug.nl/ggdc/historicaldevelopment/maddison/data/mpd2020.xlsx"
read.xlsx(url_maddison, sheet = 3)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this on Ubuntu with R 4.2.1 and RStudio 2022.07.1 Build 554.

Comment: @jay.sf maybe the problem occurs only on Windows, I don't know yet. Thank you for the info!